# Gaussian blur using fft

Tags: c++, image-processing, signal-processing

I implement a method that blurs an image using a Gaussian like this:

```
- image I , size = WxH
- kernel K , size = MxM
- padded the kernel PD to the size of the image
  i.e for an image 5x5 and a kernel 3x3 after padding the kernel looks like:
    0 0 0 0 0
    0 x x x 0
    0 x x x 0
    0 x x x 0
    0 0 0 0 0 
where X is the value from the original kernel
- performed 2d fft on the padded kernel PD (FFT_K)
- performed 2d fft on the image I (FFT_I)
- multiplied FFT_I * FFT_K (FFT_RES)
- perfomed fft on FFT_RES
- shifted the FFT_RES (RESULT)
```

The result contains some aliasing on the edges.

Here is the result:

[image]

If you notice in the right image you will see that it is aliased in both dimensions.

Is the above algorithm correct?

The implementation is with C++ and fftw3.

Comment: Just confirming, for a 3x3 kernel, the "aliasing" (which is is most likely not actually) is within the first 2 pixels, correct?

Comment: Actually, I'm going to roll this guess as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your above algorithm is correct with a slight caviate.

When you pad your image with 0's, those zeros are actually used in the convolution. In the FFT space, this will add huge high freqency components around the edge of the image. In non-FFT space, this means that, up to 1-the kernel size on the edge, the 0's are rolled in, which will give you odd looking results on the edge. People typically handle this in two ways:

1. Simply throw out 1 kernel size border around the image after convolution.
2. Mirror the edge into the pad instead of filling it with zeros.

For best results, I'll often do both 1 and 2 (to get an actual image and to eliminate  the high frequency edge in the Fourier space).

Comment: Thanks for the response. If you notice above I do not pad the image but I pad the kernel to the size of the image

Comment: @gosum Ah, then the source of your problem you need to pad the image as well. Put simply, think about doing the convolution in the top left corer of the image. Your kernel will only overlap 4/9 pixels. Where does it get the rest of the 9 pixels? Simply put, it doesn't, and the above algorithm produces nonsensical data (predictable-but-useless) output when that happens.

Comment: so I need to pad the image as W+2*M, H+2*M using the 2nd method u proposed. When I pad the kernel I set zeros?

Comment: @gosom yes. The image really only needs to be padded with half the window size (again, think of the top left corner, you only need 3/2=1 row to overlap all 9 pixels) so the image and kernal both end up being W+M-1,H+M-1. It should be noted that this'll only allow you to fudge the corners at best, so you *SHOULD* throw away the edges anyway if you doing any further analytics on the image. Also most FFT implementations go much faster if the dimensions of the data are powers of 2.